# In k8s how to setup to demo `kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-`?

Tags: kubernetes

To untaint my nodes, my scripts use ...

```
# kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

but I want to deliberately taint my node to test this untaint functionality. I tried this variant and it works fine ...

```
# kubectl taint nodes foo foo=DoNotSchedulePods:NoExecute 
# kubectl taint nodes foo foo:NoExecute-   
node/foo untainted
```

**but** I can't see how to set up so I can test the specific taint that I need to get rid of. I tried e.g.

```
# kubectl taint nodes foo foo=node-role.kubernetes.io/master     
error: unknown taint spec: foo=node-role.kubernetes.io/master
```

How to put it into situation where I can test the aforementioned untainted command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To untaint the node:

```
 kubectl taint node <Node Name> node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

To taint the node:

```
 kubectl taint node <Node Name> node-role.kubernetes.io/master=:NoSchedule
```